# Log4j2 highlight pattern not working in text-editor?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, slf4j

I am using log4j2 for logging my application on Wildfly server (Jboss 8).

I want a customized color coding for my logs which is working perfectly fine when I see logs on my console/terminal.

Following is the pattern:

log4j.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
    <Routing name="Routing">
      <Routes pattern="$${ctx:logFileName}">

        <Route>

         <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="standalone/log/platform-${ctx:logFileName}.log" filePattern="standalone/log/platform-${ctx:logFileName}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz" append="true">

            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%X{id}] %style{[%X{logFileName}}{magenta}] [%t] %highlight{[%-5level]}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=magenta} %style{%c{1}:%L}{cyan} - %highlight{%msg%n%throwable}{INFO=white,TRACE=magenta}"/>


                         .....
```

However, when I try to open my logfile in text-editor like vi or gedit, I get unknown characters like:

```
[32m15:56:30.536 DEBUG com.syn.test.Test.main() @15 - this is debug message
[m[32m15:56:30.539 DEBUG com.syn.test.Test.main() @19 - this is debug messge 
[m
```

I know the color coding would not work on a text-editor, but how not to have unknown characters in my editor and also be able to **see color coding in the console**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those characters you're seeing are called [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Most terminals and some text viewers automatically translate those properly into the respective colors.

I've typically seen these codes only used for

1. Console/terminal logs
2. Scanning logs that will be viewed with `more <filename>` or `less -r <filename>`
3. Reading and analyzing logs with some other ANSI-friendly tool or log parser

With production and real server logs, I've seen that these colors are typically not used. Having those escape codes can make it somewhat more difficult to parse for log searches, is less "standard", take up extra space, and don't add anything really to the log content itself.

If you really want these colors to be able to view logs but don't want them in the server logs that get distributed or archived, I'd configure two logs in your `log4j` config; one is a console/terminal/pretty-viewer log and one is for archival and search purposes.